# How to change direction of bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

So I have to date fields in a very short amount of place 300 X 250. There are two input fields for dates. I would like to have one datepicker with normal direction, while the other one, should point to the right of the textfield.

So I would like to have this one for the first textfield:

[image]

And this one for the second:

[image]

Comment: Consider adding a custom parameter controlling it.

Comment: @Itay, well, brilliant, how to change css for that stuff?

Comment: Did you try inspecting it with the browser's inspector to see how is it positioned and understand how to position it by yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is **no straight option in bootstrap**, but this can done by a **`CSS` hack**.

Overriding the existing `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

```
.datepicker:before {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
border-left: 7px solid transparent;
border-right: 7px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
position: absolute;
top: -7px;
left: 190px;  // I made a change here 
}

.datepicker:after {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
border-left: 6px solid transparent;
border-right: 6px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
position: absolute;
top: -6px;
left: 191px;  // I made a change here 
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/261/)

Comment: Damn, just figure it out myself, cambe back to post an answer and .... i'm 38 seconds late! Anyway... You are right! Point, points, points

Comment: @JackieChan Glad to help.  It usually happens here :)

Comment: @JackieChan You should accept this answer with the green 'V' sign.

Comment: You should know that I can accept the answer only after 10 or 8 minutes of submitting the question...

Comment: Done! However I have run into another issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307610/nested-resources-in-css-with-after-and-before