# Nested resources in css with :after and :before

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I need to differentiate on between finish / start date. So I would like on `datepicker` CSS rules applied to one text-field and others to the other.

```
<input id="mzti-start-date"  type="text" name="start_date" class="datepicker mzti-dp-width mzti-field-height" placeholder="Start date">
<input id="mzti-finish-date" type="text" name="finish_date" class="datepicker mzti-dp-width mzti-field-height" placeholder="End date">
```

And here were my CSS files:

```
#mzti-finish-date.datepicker:before {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
border-left: 7px solid transparent;
border-right: 7px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
position: absolute;
top: -7px;
left: 190px;  // I made a change here 
}

#mzti-finish-date .datepicker:after {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
border-left: 6px solid transparent;
border-right: 6px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
position: absolute;
top: -6px;
left: 191px;  // I made a change here 
}
```

Unfortunately I was not able to figure out why the rules under `mzti-finish-date` do not apply to the finish-date box.

Comment: You have an extra space on `#mzti-finish-date .datepicker:after` before the `.datepicker`.

Comment: @Jackie Chan, have you been able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's a space in your second selector.

```css
#mzti-finish-date .datepicker:after
```

Should be

```css
#mzti-finish-date.datepicker:after
```

But really should be (because IDs are unique)

```css
#mzti-finish-date:after
```

Comment: It's not going to work because a datepicker is added on the bottom of the document, hence nesting doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The order of elements is completely unrelated.